# How many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose rank ($M_{5 \times 8}) = 3$ and for $Mv=b$ the rank of $[M|b]$ augmented is 4.

How many solutions?

I don't understand what I am supposed to do here. With the given rank = 3 I understand there are 3 leading ones and 5 free variables, but I don't understand how the augment rank changes the problem and how to find the number of solutions.

If someone could walk me through this problem type, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

If the rank of the coefficient matrix is 3, but the augmented rank is 4, it means you have an equation $0=b_4$ where $b_4 \neq 0$ is an entry in $b$. So the system is inconsistent and you have no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It means that $b$ is linearly independent of the columns of $M$. (The span of $\{M[:,k]\mid k=1:8\}\cup\{b\}$ is larger than that one of $\{M[:,k]\mid k=1:8\}$.) So the equation
$$\tag{LI}\label{LI}
\sum_{k=1}^8 M[:,k]\cdot \nu_k + b\cdot \mu = 0
$$
has only a solution for $\mu=0$. But if you want to solve the problem $M\nu=b$ you need a solution with $\mu=-1$ for \eqref{LI}. Therefore, \eqref{LI} has no solution.